# Any example to have a java class instance to call once and use in all scenarios in karate with different feature files

Tags: karate

I have been using DBUtils class from karate demo, i knew this class was nothing to deal with karate. I have a concern like an example which was given has DBUtlis class is called in background for each and every scenario and it should be mentioned in all featurefiles Background:.

Anything like we configure once and use that DB instance variable in all scenarios?? If yes examples please.

**Update after below comment by peter:**

**config:**
[image]

**Main Feature File:**
[image]

**Reusing DB instance in another feature file**

[image]

Please confirm whether this is right approach or not?

**Dry Run for a String:**

```
var result = karate.callSingle('classpath:featureFiles/dbBackground.feature', config);

  config.PersonName = result.name;
```

**Main Feature:**

```
Feature: DB Background

Background:
    * def name = "Sandeep";
```

**Other feature:**

```
Feature: Get Account Details

Background:

    * def actualname = PersonName;

@golden
Scenario: user 1 details
 * def expectedFormat = read('../requestFiles/format.json')

        Given url 'https://reqres.in/api/users'
        And params ({id: '1'})
        When method Get
        Then match response.data.email == "george.bluth@reqres.in"
        Then print '###################################name is: ', actualname
        Then print '###################################name is: ', PersonName
```

**Console result seeing null:**

[image]

**Updated Dry run 2:**

```
Feature: DB Background

Background:

    * def name = "Sandeep";

    @golden
Scenario: user sample details
 * def expectedFormat = read('../requestFiles/format.json')

        Given url 'https://reqres.in/api/users'
        And params ({id: '1'})
        When method Get
        Then match response.data.email == "george.bluth@reqres.in"
```

**output:**

```
19:31:33.416 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $['data']['email']
19:31:33.416 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] ###################################name is:  Sandeep
19:31:33.432 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] ###################################name is:  Sandeep
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can initialize it in `karate-config.js` and then it will be a global variable.

Also look at `karate.callSingle()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

Comment: Hey Peter, i have updated original post with an example. Let me know if that is right approach or not?

Comment: @SandeepPadala yeah. I don't understand why you need to wrap. won't `config.db = result.db;` be simpler, now all your features can use `db` directly.

Comment: Gotcha!! Thanks a ton, long live!!

Comment: Hey Peter i am see null value for dry run, could please check my code snippet and say where i was wrong?

Comment: @SandeepPadala should be `def DbUtils = Java.type('ApiTest.DbUtils')` if still stuck follow this process please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: i had comment that, just using * def name = "Sandeep";

Comment: @SandeepPadala giving up. bye

Comment: Dont Giveup, issue was the background which i am defining on a feature file should contain at least one scenario, so that when that scenario executes then that background values are setting globally!! Finally it worked but i dont want a scenario dependence which needs to be executed for sure. Hope you got it! Thanks Again.

Comment: @SandeepPadala no I don't. if you have more questions, open a new one or submit an example, thanks.